# Multiline Regex .Net

Tags: .net, regex

I am currently attempting to extract the following as paragraphs using Regex within .Net 3.5
At the beginning of each paragraph is an identifying phrase that denotes the start of the sequence, in this case `StartMarker`. Thereafter, a variable number of lines, each with a linefeed (`\n`) at the end. The end of the paragraph is denoted by an empty line.

Example input data is as follows

```
StartMarker:
Line1
Line2
Line3
Line4
Line5

StartMarker:
Line6
Line7
Line8

StartMarker:
Line9
Line10
```

This should yield the following matches:

Match 1

```
StartMarker:
Line1
Line2
Line3
Line4
Line5
```

Match 2

```
StartMarker:
Line6
Line7
Line8
```

Match 3

```
StartMarker:
Line9
Line10
```

I've tried `(^StartMarker.*\n)` but that only matches the first line in each segment. I've used this with global and multiline options enabled.

I was thinking something like `(^StartMarker.*)([\s\S]+\n)` but this does not work as `[\s\S]+` is greedy and captures everything after `StartMarker` until the end of the file. So I'm really not sure how to proceed. Any help here will be appreciated.

Comment: `?` after the `+` makes it non-greedy.

Comment: Thanks. I've just tried that. (^StartMarker:)([\s\S]+?\n). So now that captures everything from StartMarker: to the end of the next line. Any ideas on how I can get it to capture until the empty line?

Comment: With that non-greedy bit, I think I've worked it out. ^StartMarker:[\s\S]+?^\n. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this pattern

```
(StartMarker:[\s\S]*?)(?=(?:\r?\n)+StartMarker:|$)
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/tF5fT5/21)

Comment: At first, I thought that this was incorrect. But I see you are using it in SingleLine mode. It works too! Because I'm using multi-line mode, the following will work ^StartMarker:[\s\S]+?^\n. Easier on the eyes. For me at least :). Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Dee: That's not Singleline mode.  This regex is in the default mode, where the dot (`.`) matches any character except linefeed, and the anchors (`^` and `$`) match only the start and end of the whole string.  Singleline enables `.` to match anything, while Multiline turns `^` and `$` into *start-of-line* and *end-of-line* anchors.  There's nothing stopping you from using both modes at once:  `(?ms)^StartMarker:.*?(?=(?:\r?\n)+StartMarker:|\Z)`

Answer (score 0):

if your pattern is Absolute use this `Regex`:

```
(StartMarker:(?:\sLine\d+)*)
```

otherwise if your Line can be anything use this `Regex`:

```
(StartMarker:(?:\s.+)*)
```